# How to write custom queries in codeigniter that includes OR, AND, LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having two tables from which i have to fetch the records based on Search criteria..
here is the actual query which i tried earlier without using active record.

**Without active record:**

```
$query = $this->db->query("select A.* from A LEFT JOIN B ON A.AId=B.BId where
        (A.Title like '%$searchstring%' OR B.Name like '%$searchstring%') and A.Status='1' and A.Type IN (0) and
        (A.UserId = '$userid' or A.Public='0')  Limit $start,20");
```

> Please note those parenthesis which i have enclosed like this
>   `(A.Title like '%$searchstring%' OR B.Name like '%$searchstring%')`

Actually this seems to be working fine if the searchstring is **plaintext i.e without quotations**. But if it contains **'** or **"** quotes it returns database error

So i tried writing active record this way

```
        $this->db->select("A.*");
        $this->db->from('Bloop as A');
        $this->db->join('Keywords as B', 'A.BloopId=B.BloopId','LEFT');
        $this->db->where_in('A.Type','1');
        $this->db->where('A.Status','1');
        $this->db->like('A.Title', $string);
        $this->db->OR_like('B.Name', $string);
        $this->db->where('A.UserId',$userid);
        $this->db->or_where('A.Public',0);
        $this->db->limit(20,$start);
        $query = $this->db->get();
```

But this returned incorrect results, The reason is the **OR** condition is **not enclosed in parenthesis**.

Can someone correct my query..

Thanks..

Answer (score 4):

Hope this will help you.

```
    $this->db->select("A.*");
    $this->db->from('Bloop as A');
    $this->db->join('Keywords as B', 'A.BloopId=B.BloopId','LEFT');
    $this->db->where_in('A.Type','1');
    $this->db->where('A.Status','1');
    $this->db->where("(A.Title LIKE '%$string%' OR B.Name LIKE '%$string%')");
    $this->db->where("('A.UserId' = '$userid' OR 'A.Public' = 0)");
    $this->db->limit(20,$start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to try this with a `false`

```
$query = $this->db->query("select A.* from A LEFT JOIN B ON A.AId=B.BId where
    (A.Title like '%$searchstring%' OR B.Name like '%$searchstring%') and A.Status='1' and A.Type IN (0) and
    (A.UserId = '$userid' or A.Public='0')  Limit $start,20",false);
```

Note, passing a second argument as `false`.

You can also do it the CI way:

```
$like   = "( A.Title like '%".$string."%' OR B.Name like '%".$string."%' )";
$this->db->select("A.*");
$this->db->from('Bloop as A');
$this->db->join('Keywords as B', 'A.BloopId=B.BloopId','LEFT');
$this->db->where_in('A.Type','1');
$this->db->where('A.Status','1');
//$this->db->like('A.Title', $string);
//$this->db->OR_like('B.Name', $string);
$this->db->where($like, false);
$this->db->where('A.UserId',$userid);
$this->db->or_where('A.Public',0);
$this->db->limit(20,$start);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Will it makes the difference.. What actually is the use of FALSE? many thanks

Comment: `false` as the second parameter tells not to `escape` the query passed to it, Did it worked for you?

Comment: Just an addition: $this->db->escape_like_str() in your $string to avoid SQL injection. Check http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html => `$like   = "( A.Title like '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($string)."%' OR B.Name like '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($string)."%' )";`